# React-Leaflet: Markers disappear when panning the map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a map created with `react-leaflet`. The problem is that when I move the map in mobile devices, markers that are close to map container edge get disappeared.

I have something like 4000 markers on my map. What I expect is to markers never disappear, even if they went out of the visible map area.

Map Component:

```
<MapContainer
        ref={map}
        center={[31.89448, 54.36954]}
        zoom={5}
        worldCopyJump
        boundsOptions={{ padding: [50, 50] }}
        zoomControl={false}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        whenCreated={setMap}
        className={classes.leafletContainer}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {markerData ? (
          <MarkerClusterGroup>
            {markerData.map((singleMarker) => (
              <Marker
                key={`${singleMarker.organization_id}y`}
                icon={L.icon({
                  iconUrl: singleMarker.logo,
                  iconSize: [38, 95],
                  iconAnchor: [22, 94],
                  popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
                  shadowUrl: null,
                  shadowSize: [68, 95],
                  shadowAnchor: [22, 94],
                })}
                position={[singleMarker.lat, singleMarker.long]}
              >
                <Popup className={classes.popup}>
                  <MapCard organizationId={singleMarker.organization_id} />
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            ))}
          </MarkerClusterGroup>
        ) : (
          <Grid item md={12} className={classes.mapLoading}>
            <Typography>در حال بارگذاری موسسه ها...</Typography>
          </Grid>
        )}

        {selectedOrganizationData && (
          <Marker
            key={selectedOrganizationData?.id}
            icon={L.icon({
              iconUrl: selectedOrganizationData?.logo,
              iconSize: [38, 95],
              iconAnchor: [22, 94],
              popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
              shadowUrl: null,
              shadowSize: [68, 95],
              shadowAnchor: [22, 94],
            })}
            position={[
              selectedOrganizationData?.addresses[0]?.lat,
              selectedOrganizationData?.addresses[0]?.long,
            ]}
          >
            <Popup className={classes.popup}>
              <MapCard organizationId={selectedOrganizationData?.id} />
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        )}
      </MapContainer>
```

Map Css:

```
leafletContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 10,
    borderRadius: '0 0 21px 21px',
    boxShadow: '0 10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)',

    '& .leaflet-div-icon': {
      border: 'none',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },

    '& .leaflet-top': {
      bottom: '4px !important',
      top: 'unset !important',
    },

    '& img.leaflet-marker-icon': {
      background: 'url("../marker.svg")',
      backgroundSize: '100% 86%',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: '100% 100%',
      height: '38px !important',
      padding: '10px',
      borderRadius: '50%',
    },
  },
```

So far, I have tested `worldCopyJump` property but nothing changed.

Comment: What do you mean they disappear when they're close to the edge?  Do they reappear when panned back into view?  Do they disappear once their latlng is out of view, or once even the smallest bit of marker is out of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were experiencing the same issue when panning the map. Each marker disappeared when about 50% off the screen. Panning in the opposite direction made them appear back, now when they were about 50% back inside the screen. In our case the issue was caused by the 'removeOutsideVisibleBounds' parameter in the MarkerClusterGroup setup.

We modified the parameter from:
removeOutsideVisibleBounds={true}

To:
removeOutsideVisibleBounds={false}

Using: react 17.0.2 + react-leaflet 3.2.0 + react-leaflet-markercluster 3.0.0-rc1